# powershell function return

Tags: powershell

I try to start a function of an script out of another script.
I want to save the return into a variable but this doesn't work.

script1.ps1:

```
function test
{
  return "hallo"
}
```

script2.ps1:

```
./script1.ps1; $p=test

or
$p = ./script1.ps1; test
```

It seems that `$p` is null, but I don't know what's wrong.
Can anybody please help me?
thx

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
. ./script1.ps1; $p=test
```

Why: you have to load the function into current scope (that's the period at the beginning – the *dot source operator*).

If you use ';', then completely new statement begins. So from you example `$p = ./script.ps1; test`, you assign output from script.ps1 to `$p` and then run the function.

Comment: that's not a comma, <- that is; It's a period. <- like that ;-)